# Jfrog Artifactory CLI does not publish all go dependencies

Tags: go, dependencies, artifactory, jfrog-cli

[This](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Go+Registry) article pretty much covers how you could source your golang dependencies into an artifactory instance.
I configured the artifactory endpoint with `jfrog rt go-config` command. Then created a build with `jfrog rt go build --no-registry` command. After that `jfrog rt go-publish my-go-artifactory-storage --self=false --deps=ALL` run successful uploading about 70 direct dependencies to artifactory.
So I set the `GOPRPOXY` env var, removed the cache from the machine, and started to build again.

I expected that every dependencies will be downloaded from the artifactory. But sadly it did not happen. Indirect or transitive dependencies were not published. Direct dependencies were downloaded fine, but the others throw 404 as they were not published to artifactory earlier.

I tried to lock all the dependencies using `go list -m all` and adding the result to the go.mod file, but rebuild (with --no-registry) and republish did not result uploading more than earlier did.

As the article I linked above suggests you to manually download transitives to be able to publish them I tried to use `go mod vendor` for the purpose. Rebuild, republish. No transitives in artifactory. I simple does not get how they meant downloading them manually (~350 they are). And where shall I put them for publish command to find them?

Personally, I see no point in hosting direct dependencies only in artifactory, so I hope there is a way of publishing every package dependencies. What did I miss?

Do you have a working set of command for that purpose?